# Replacing only some rows in the same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a column:

```
name 
Jules
Jules
Jules
Jules
Vince
```

I need to replace only the top-half of ocurrences of `Jules` for `Quentin`

Such as:

```
name 
Quentin
Quentin
Jules
Jules
Vince
```

How do I replace only some values in a given column?

To further ellaborate, the location of `Jules` will never be the same.

I've thought about iterating like this, but it did not work:

```
countOfJules = df['name'].value_counts()['Jules']
halfLenght = int(countoftbd/2)
listed = df['name'].to_list()
counter = 1

for eachname in listed:
    if eachname == 'Jules' and counter <= halfLenght:
        listed[:] == 'Quentin'
        counter += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rather straightforward:

```
# where name is Jules
is_jules = df['name'].eq('Jules')

# total `Jules` in `name`
num_jules = is_jules.sum()

# first half `Jules`
first_half = is_jules.cumsum().le(num_jules//2)

df.loc[is_jules & first_half, 'name'] = 'Quentin'
```

Output:

```
      name
0  Quentin
1  Quentin
2    Jules
3    Jules
4    Vince
```

Answer (score 0):

The term that is usually used for accessing a subset of an array (or list, dataframe, etc) is slicing. The [Pandas documentation has a nice section on slicing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) as well as other ways of accessing specific members of a dataframe. In your case, it looks like you are selecting based on index in the array, in which case you can use `df[start:stop]` where `start` and `stop` are the indices you want to access between.